# SQL Server : insert Arabic letter to database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

First of all, this problem doesn't exist when the text is just English, but when I insert Arabic text, I got the problem.

Look at my code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertToPinTableCardActivation
   (@callerID VARCHAR (200),  
    @vAccount VARCHAR (200))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @textEnglish NVARCHAR(1000) --missing length previously

    SET @textEnglish = 'Dear customer, your Card linked to account number '+ @vAccount --missing set keyword
    SET @textEnglish = @textEnglish + ' is now activated. Thank you for banking with us.'
    SET @textEnglish = 'عزيزي الزبون، تم تفعيل بطاقة الصراف الآلي التابعة لحسابكم رقم ' + @vAccount

    INSERT INTO pinData([CallerID], [body], [processed]) 
    VALUES (@callerID, @textEnglish, 0)
END
```

The code creates a string of mix Arab and English, and then insert it to a table.

My problem is that look what it is being inserted to the table

[image]

even though i already made the field `body` as nvarchar

could you help please

#### Update 1

I am inserting from my sql server when executing the stored procedure

#### update 2

if i go to the table and insert the data manually in arab, the arab letters shows correctly

Comment: How about the field within your destination Table

Comment: It could be that your database viewer (looks like SSMS possibly?) is not unicode capable.  Try writing a little winforms or wpf app in .NET and see if it selects the correct data. (console app won't work because the console doesn't display unicode; though you could set a breakpoint and view the data in the VS IDE, since VS is unicode capable)

Comment: @KamranFarzami it is nvarchar

Comment: @JNevill no no it is nvarchar not varchar

Comment: @SamAxe who talked about VS :) i 'm inserting from my stored procedure inside my sql server 2008

Comment: Sorry yep. I see that now in your question. I agree with @SamAxe that it may be your client. Some clients allow you to switch between UNICODE and ANSI mode

Comment: Sorry... to specify further, you are not in your SQL Server. You must access your SQL Server with a client. In that client it's important that you specify that you are working with UNICODE (if there is an option). It might not be the problem, but it's a good place to start considering everything is NVARCHAR() downstream.

Comment: @JNevill i am using my sql management studio, really nothing else, you may know the client that they are using to insert to the sql server. does that help? need more info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you want to insert **Unicode** string literals, you **must prepend** your string literal with an **`N`** prefix - try this:

```
SET @textEnglish = N'...(insert your Arabic text here)...'
```

Otherwise, your text is reverted back to a **non-Unicode** format before being stored - and that's why you lose the Arabic text....

And also: if you're concatenating with `VARCHAR` parameters, I'd recommend using an explicit `CAST` to `NVARCHAR` (include a **length** when casting!):

```
SET @textEnglish = N'Dear customer, your Card linked to account number ' + CAST(@vAccount AS NVARCHAR(100))
```

Comment: i really appreciate it, it works perfectly, please last thing, do you know how to add a new line? so i can separate the arab with the english. each in one line

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: depends on where and how you want to display that text in the end - if you send this to an HTML page, you could add a `<br/>` between those texts. Otherwise it gets a bit messy (in SSMS - from a language like C#, just send the usual CR+LF characters, SQL Server will happily store those for you)

Comment: i just want to insert the data in two lines to my table, because there is another app that automatically reads these data and send them to the customer