# arabic language insert in MS SQL table

Tags: sql-server, database, arabic

I have a table constant 
[image: table desgin]

I add arabic language to it, and doesn't make problem but, i start to add new one and doesnt work

[image: after add data]

Comment: Is the string in your insert statement missing the `N` prefix to denote that the string is unicode?

Comment: To support @Bridge : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800188/sql-server-insert-arabic-letter-to-database

Comment: yes i missing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just Missing the N prefix before insert in the table

```
SET @WordAr= N'...(insert your Arabic text here)...'
```